# Edittext value disappear when scrolling recyclerview in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, position, scrollview

I have called recyclerview in which my arraylist is attached with the adapter. And when adapter has its own row file in which I have taken one edit text and manually I can enter the amount.

But the issue is when I scroll the recyclerview, edit text value has gone. So can't see the values whichever entered by me.

***Adapter Class***

```
public class AddSecondarySalesOrderProductDetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    ArrayList<SecondarySalesProductDetailsModel> mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel;
    ArrayList<String> mArrProductQuantity;
    private int mViewItem = 1;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    ImageView mImageDeleteProduct;
    private String mProductName, mProductAvaQuantity, mProductSKU, mOrderedQuantity;

    /**
     * Adapter contains the data to be displayed
     */
    public AddSecondarySalesOrderProductDetailsAdapter(Activity mActivity, ArrayList<SecondarySalesProductDetailsModel>
            mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        this.mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel = mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel;
        mArrProductQuantity = new ArrayList<>();
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_add_secondary_sales_order_product_details, parent,
                false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel.get(position) != null ? mViewItem : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        final SecondarySalesProductDetailsModel mAllProductDetailsModel = mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel.get(position);
        ((CustomViewHolder) holder).mImageDeleteProduct.setTag(position);

        mProductName = mAllProductDetailsModel.getProductName();
        mProductAvaQuantity = String.valueOf(mAllProductDetailsModel.getAvalQty());
        mProductSKU = mAllProductDetailsModel.getSku();

        ((CustomViewHolder) holder).mTextProductName.setText(mProductName);
        ((CustomViewHolder) holder).mTextProductAvaQuantity.setText(mProductAvaQuantity);
        ((CustomViewHolder) holder).mTextProductSKU.setText(mProductSKU);

        ((CustomViewHolder) holder).mImageDeleteProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel.size());

                if (mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel.size() == 0) {
                    AddSecondarySalesOrderProductDetailFragment.mRelativeNoRecords.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        OrderedQuantityTextWatcher textWatcher = new OrderedQuantityTextWatcher(holder, ((CustomViewHolder) holder).mEditOrderedQuantity, position);
        ((CustomViewHolder) holder).mEditOrderedQuantity.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        ((CustomViewHolder) holder).mEditOrderedQuantity.setTag(position);
    }

    private class OrderedQuantityTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private EditText editText;
        private int position;
        private RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;

        public OrderedQuantityTextWatcher(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, EditText editText, int
                pos) {
            this.holder = holder;
            this.editText = editText;
            this.position = pos;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
//            mOrderedQuantity = mEditOrderedQuantity.getText().toString().trim();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
//            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            int position = (int) editText.getTag();

            Common.insertLog("Position: " + position);
            Common.insertLog("Value: " + editable);

            SecondarySalesProductDetailsModel secondarySalesProductDetailsModel = new
                    SecondarySalesProductDetailsModel();
            secondarySalesProductDetailsModel.setId(mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel.get(position).getId());
            secondarySalesProductDetailsModel.setProductName
                    (mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel.get(position).getProductName());
            secondarySalesProductDetailsModel.setAvalQty(mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel
                    .get(position).getAvalQty());
            secondarySalesProductDetailsModel.setOrderedQty(editable.toString().trim());
            secondarySalesProductDetailsModel.setSku(mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel.get
                    (position).getSku());
            secondarySalesProductDetailsModel.setProductId(mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel
                    .get(position).getProductId());
            secondarySalesProductDetailsModel.setSelected(mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel
                    .get(position).getSelected());
//            mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel.add(secondarySalesProductDetailsModel);

            Intent intent = new Intent(AppConstants.BROADCAST_SEND_SECONDARY_PRODUCTS);
            intent.putExtra(AppConstants.BUNDLE_BROADCAST_ORDERED_QUANTITY,
                    secondarySalesProductDetailsModel);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mActivity).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mArrSecondarySalesProductDetailsModel.size();
    }

    /**
     * Initialization of components
     */
    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView mTextProductName, mTextProductAvaQuantity, mTextProductSKU;
        EditText mEditOrderedQuantity;
        ImageView mImageDeleteProduct;

        public CustomViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.mImageDeleteProduct = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id
                    .image_raw_secondary_sales_order_delete);
            this.mTextProductName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_raw_secondary_sales_order_product_name);
            this.mTextProductAvaQuantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id
                    .text_raw_secondary_sales_order_ava_quantity);
            this.mTextProductSKU = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id
                    .text_raw_secondary_sales_order_product_sku);
            this.mEditOrderedQuantity = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id
                    .edit_raw_secondary_sales_order_quantity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36278503/9763253

Answer (score 2):

Fo those still looking for the solution,  here is solution for them

steps :

1. create a hashmap something like ths -
   **HashMap<Integer, Network> editedMapList = new HashMap<Integer, Network>();**
2. In onBind method based on textchanged add the changed item in the hashmap based on position
3. When when scroll down row will recreate for that u have set value again something like this in onBind method of adapter.
   *//For recycled item update*
   **if (editedMapList.containsKey(position)) {
   ((NetworkItemViewHolder) holder).etUsername.setText(editedMapList.get(position).getUsername());
   }**

Note: Here the logic is when u scroll down row will recreate that means onBind method will call, so wat u have to do is update the row edittext based on position from the editted hashmap.

Hope it helps !
Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

i model class create one more field and set as empty on object creation , set to edit text in onBindViewHolder() , on text change update that object too..

Answer (score 0):

Problem : if Your edittext value is 0 on Scrolling the recyclerview

Solution : then Use below Code to your Edittext inside textwatcher method afterTextchange()

```
Code : yourEditTextName.setSelection(yourEditTextName.getText().length());
```