# Android - Recycler View item get swapped when scrolled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Can somebody explain what is the problem.

I have a recycler grid view with each item consisting countdown timer and view which changes after a countdown time is completed.

But the problem arises when I do scroll to down and back to top, my items were change for other items in the list, and if I do scroll again, the items again are changed.

This is my adapter.

```
public class TableTransactionRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TableTransactionRecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<TableInfo> tableList;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;
    private static Context context;
    private static SharedPreferences preferences;

    private static List<ViewHolder> lstHolders;
    public Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lstHolders) {
                for (ViewHolder holder : lstHolders) {
                    holder.updateTimeRemaining();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public TableTransactionRecyclerView(Context context, ArrayList<TableInfo> tableList, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.tableList = tableList;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.context = context;
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(CommonConsts.MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        lstHolders = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ViewHolder vh;

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.table_transaction_row_layout, parent, false);
        vh = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        synchronized (lstHolders) {
            lstHolders.add(vh);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(tableList, position, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tableList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        public ImageButton popupMenuBtn;
        private ProgressBar showLoadingImage;
        private ImageView successTick;
        private ImageView tableIcon;
        private LinearLayout processingLayout;
        private View lineView;
        private LatoTextView transactionAmountTextView;
        private LatoTextView timerCountTextView;
        private ArrayList<TableInfo> tableList;
        private int position;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.table_id_text_view);
            popupMenuBtn = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pop_menu_btn);
            showLoadingImage = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_loading_image);
            successTick = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.success_image_view);
            lineView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_id);
            tableIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.table_icon);
            processingLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.processing_layout);
            transactionAmountTextView = (LatoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.transaction_amount_text_view);
            timerCountTextView = (LatoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timer_count_down_id);
        }

        public void bind(final ArrayList<TableInfo> tableList, final int position, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            TableInfo item = tableList.get(position);
            this.tableList = tableList;
            this.position = position;
            textView.setText(item.getTableNumber());
            if (item.getIsProcessing()) {
                showLoadingImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                successTick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tableIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                processingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                transactionAmountTextView.setText(Utils.setFormattedText(String.valueOf(item.getTransactionAmt())));

                synchronized (lstHolders) {
                    updateTimeRemaining();
                }

            } else {
                showLoadingImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tableIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                processingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            setLayout(tableList, position, item.getIsProcessing(), item.isLastTransactionSuccess());

        }

        public void setLayout(final ArrayList<TableInfo> tableList, final int position, boolean isTransaction, boolean isSuccess) {
            final TableInfo item = tableList.get(position);
            if(isTransaction){
                item.setHandler(null);
                item.setUIChangeCompletedSuccess(true);
                showLoadingImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tableIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                processingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                transactionAmountTextView.setText(Utils.setFormattedText(String.valueOf(item.getTransactionAmt())));
                lineView.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.txn_view_drawable));
            }else{
                showLoadingImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tableIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                processingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if(item.isUIChangeCompletedSuccess()) {
                    item.setUIChangeCompletedSuccess(false);

                    if (isSuccess) {
                        successTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        lstHolders.get(position).lineView.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.txn_success_view_drawable));
                        Handler handler;
                        if (item.getHandler() == null) {
                            handler = new Handler();
                            item.setHandler(handler);
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    lstHolders.get(position).lineView.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.txn_view_drawable));
                                    successTick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    item.setHandler(null);
                                }
                            }, 25000);
                        }
                    } else {
                        successTick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        lstHolders.get(0).lineView.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.txn_unsuccess_view_drawable));
                        Handler handler;
                        if (item.getHandler() == null) {
                            handler = new Handler();
                            item.setHandler(handler);
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    lstHolders.get(position).lineView.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.txn_view_drawable));
                                    successTick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    item.setHandler(null);
                                }
                            }, 25000);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void updateTimeRemaining() {
            timerCountTextView.setText(preferences.getString(tableList.get(position).getTableId(), ""));
        }
    }
}
```

and i have set adapter like this:

```
mAdapter = new TableTransactionRecyclerView(this, tableList, this);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 4, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I have also looked at the problem in following links which didnot solved my problem.

[Recyclerview changing items when is scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613463/recyclerview-changing-items-when-is-scrolled)

[Recyclerview Changing Items During Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065267/recyclerview-changing-items-during-scroll)

Comment: holder.setIsRecyclable(false); add this line to you onBindView

Comment: yes it solved that problem but now view that needs to be changed after countdown timer is not changing....

Comment: yeah that will not change because you set properties to Recyclable false. You said you need to change the view after some countdownd!!. for this you need to sync this with you default arrayList item.and set Recyclable property to true.

Comment: no this is not applicable for your question. If you can post your code i can try help you out

Comment: can you give me your email address?

Comment: ankushbist23@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks, i am sending you a link in a mail....

Comment: mail received. can you please start this discussion over chat. I am not able  to make it. displaying some error.

Comment: Please read this solution, it wight help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200540/recyclerview-on-scrolling-values-changing-from-adapter
It will help for new comers.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the following:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {    
    return position;
}
```