# If RecyclerView scrolls, then item id changes. How to resolve this?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

This is my `PDFListAdapter class` method. I have downloaded file locally and save on Sqlite database. But if I scroll my `RecyclerView`, then I am having different item id. If not scroll `RecyclerView` then item id is perfect.

The problem is when I scroll down the `RecyclerView` the item id changes. That is, I can fit one item on the screen at once. When I scroll to the second item, it saves different file and opens different.

```
public class PDFListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PDFListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<NotesResponseInfo> pdfModelClasses;
    Context context;
    static NotesResponseInfo pdfList;
    String final_nav_opt_name;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String TAG = "PDFListAdapter";
    private NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    int id = 1;
    DatabaseNotes databaseNotes;
    MyViewHolder holder;
    Downloader downloader;
    int deepak =0 ;

    public PDFListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NotesResponseInfo> pdfModelClasses, String final_nav_opt_name) {
        this.context = context;
        this.pdfModelClasses = pdfModelClasses;
        this.final_nav_opt_name = final_nav_opt_name;
        databaseNotes = new DatabaseNotes(context);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtBookName, txtBookTitle, txtBookBookDateOFIssue, txtBookCategory, txtDownload;
        LinearLayout layout_open_pdf, layout_download_note_option;
        ImageView imgDownloadNote, imgCancelDownloadNote;
        ProgressBar progress_download_note;
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            txtBookName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtBookName);
            txtBookTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtBookTitle);
            txtBookBookDateOFIssue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtBookBookDateOFIssue);
            txtBookCategory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtBookCategory);
            txtDownload = view.findViewById(R.id.txtDownload);
            layout_open_pdf = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_open_pdf);
            layout_download_note_option = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_download_note_option);
            imgDownloadNote = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgDownloadNote);
            progress_download_note = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_download_note);
            imgCancelDownloadNote = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgCancelDownloadNote);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()) .inflate(R.layout.layout_pdf_adapter, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder1, final int index) {
        final int position = index;
        pdfList = pdfModelClasses.get(position);
        final DownloadedNotesDataBase databaseNotes = new DownloadedNotesDataBase(context);
        holder1.txtBookName.setText(pdfList.getSubjectName().toUpperCase());
        holder1.txtBookTitle.setText(StringUtils.getTrimString(pdfList.getTypeName()));
        holder1.txtBookBookDateOFIssue.setText(pdfList.getType());
        holder1.txtBookCategory.setText(StringUtils.getTrimString(pdfList.getDescription()));
        if (databaseNotes.isPurchasedNoteSaved(pdfList.getId(), final_nav_opt_name)) {
            holder1.txtDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder1.layout_download_note_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder1.txtDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder1.layout_download_note_option.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        holder1.layout_open_pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pdfList = pdfModelClasses.get(position);
                 holder = holder1;
                Log.e("PDFListAdapter", "layout_open_pdf position = "+position);
                Log.e("PDFListAdapter", "layout_open_pdf = "+pdfList.getId());
                if (databaseNotes.isPurchasedNoteSaved(pdfList.getId(), final_nav_opt_name)) {
                    DownloadeNotesModel downloadeNotesModel = databaseNotes.getNotesByID(pdfList.getId(), final_nav_opt_name);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, PDFResults.class);
                    intent.putExtra("pdfList", downloadeNotesModel.getFileLocation());
                    intent.putExtra("from", "database");
                    intent.putExtra("getSubjectName", downloadeNotesModel.getSubjectName());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Notes not downloaded. Do you want to download it?");
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            downloader = new Downloader();
                            new CheckSpace().execute(pdfList.getFileName());
                        }
                    });

                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
        });

        holder1.imgDownloadNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("PDFListAdapter", "imgDownloadNote position = "+position);
                Log.e("PDFListAdapter", "imgDownloadNote = "+pdfList.getId());
                pdfList = pdfModelClasses.get(position);
                deepak =index ;
                holder = holder1;
                if (!databaseNotes.isPurchasedNoteSaved(pdfList.getId(), final_nav_opt_name)) {
                    if (UtilsMethods.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            downloader = new Downloader();
                            new CheckSpace().execute(pdfList.getFileName());
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "storage permission is not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            PermissionCheck.checkWritePermission(context);
                        }
                    } else {
                        holder.imgDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.imgCancelDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.progress_download_note.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NoInternetActivity.class));
                    }
                }
                else Log.e("","Not in db");
            }
        });

        holder1.imgCancelDownloadNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("PDFListAdapter", "imgCancelDownloadNote position = "+position);
                Log.e("PDFListAdapter", "imgCancelDownloadNote = "+pdfList.getId());
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialogStyle).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure want to cancel download?");
                alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialog.hide();
                        downloader.cancel(true);
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pdfModelClasses.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private void startSave(final Context context, NotesResponseInfo url) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        final base_url b = new base_url();
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(b.BASE_URL);
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        AllApis downloadService = retrofit.create(AllApis.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = downloadService.downloadFileByUrl(StringUtils.getCroppedUrl(url.getFileName()));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, final Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
                    downloader.execute(response.body());
                } else {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private class Downloader extends AsyncTask<ResponseBody, Integer, Integer> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mBuilder.setContentTitle("Download")
                    .setContentText("Download in progress")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.lun);
            mBuilder.setProgress(100, 0, false);
            mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            mBuilder.setContentTitle("Download")
                    .setContentText("Download in progress")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo);
            mBuilder.setProgress(100, values[0], false);
            mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
            holder.imgDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imgCancelDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.progress_download_note.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mNotifyManager.cancelAll();
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(ResponseBody... params) {

            NotesResponseInfo item = new NotesResponseInfo();

            item = pdfModelClasses.get(deepak);

            ResponseBody body = params[0];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(pdfList.getFileName());
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();
                ContextWrapper wrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
                int lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();
                Log.w("getContentLength",""+lenghtOfFile);
                File file = wrapper.getDir("PDF", MODE_PRIVATE);
                file = new File(file, pdfList.getSubjectName() + "_" + TimeUtils.getCurrentTimeStamp() + ".pdf");
                FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
                InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                float finalValue = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[100 * 1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                int progress = 0;
                long total = 0;
                if (!(isCancelled())) {
                    while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) >0) {
                        if (UtilsMethods.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                            f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                            total += len1;
                            setProgress(Integer.parseInt(("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile))));

                     /*   progress += len1;finalValue = (float) progress/body.contentLength() *100;
                        setProgress((int) finalValue);
                        mBuilder.setProgress((int) finalValue,0,false);*/

                        } else {
                            File file1 = new File(file.getPath());
                            file1.delete();
                            cancel(true);

                        }
                    }
                    new DownloadedNotesDataBase(context).addDonloadedNotesToDatabase(file.getPath(), pdfList);
                } else {
                    File file1 = new File(file.getPath());
                    file1.delete();
                    holder.imgDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.imgCancelDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.progress_download_note.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete");
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo);
            mBuilder.setProgress(100, 100, false);
            mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
            holder.txtDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.imgDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.imgCancelDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.progress_download_note.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        private void setProgress(int progress) {
            mBuilder.setContentText("Downloading...")
                    .setContentTitle(progress + "%")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentInfo(progress + "%")
                    .setProgress(100, progress, false);
            mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
            holder.progress_download_note.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }

    public class CheckSpace extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String file_size = "";
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(params[0]);
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                int fileSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                file_size = UtilsMethods.generateFileSize(fileSize);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return file_size;
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (UtilsMethods.compareSpace(result)) {
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialogStyle).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Download this PDF of size " + result + " ?");
                alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialog.hide();
                        holder.imgDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.imgCancelDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.progress_download_note.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        startSave(context, pdfList);
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            } else {
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialogStyle).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Unable to download file. Storage space is not available");
                alertDialog.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialog.hide();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you assigning `holder = holder1`? And where you have declared the `holder`?

Comment: @pskink i have also do this but not work

Comment: @pskink If RecyclerView scrolls, then item id changes.

Comment: @pskink also give Full Adapter class please cheek

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your `onBindViewHolder` function. The changes are following.

1. Declared the pdfList variable as final and used it everywhere. It is not necessary to get the `pdfList` from the `pdfModelClasses`, each time you use it.
2. The `holder` variable is removed, as it is not actually necessary. The `holder1` is used everywhere.
3. There are some changes with the visibility of the buttons. Check `holder1.imgDownloadNote.setOnClickListener`.

I have found no  other problem in your `onBindViewHolder`. Please let me know if the modified code works.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder1, final int index) {
    final int position = index;

    // Declare the variable here and make it final. 
    final PDFList pdfList = pdfModelClasses.get(position);

    final DownloadedNotesDataBase databaseNotes = new DownloadedNotesDataBase(context);

    holder1.txtBookName.setText(pdfList.getSubjectName().toUpperCase());
    holder1.txtBookTitle.setText(StringUtils.getTrimString(pdfList.getTypeName()));
    holder1.txtBookBookDateOFIssue.setText(pdfList.getType());
    holder1.txtBookCategory.setText(StringUtils.getTrimString(pdfList.getDescription()));

    if (databaseNotes.isPurchasedNoteSaved(pdfList.getId(), final_nav_opt_name)) {
        holder1.txtDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder1.layout_download_note_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder1.txtDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder1.layout_download_note_option.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    holder1.layout_open_pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // I have the desired pdfList already, no need to get that again.
            // pdfList = pdfModelClasses.get(position);

            // Assigning to holder is not necessary.
            // holder = holder1;

            Log.e("PDFListAdapter", "layout_open_pdf position = "+position);
            Log.e("PDFListAdapter", "layout_open_pdf = "+pdfList.getId());
            if (databaseNotes.isPurchasedNoteSaved(pdfList.getId(), final_nav_opt_name)) {
                DownloadeNotesModel downloadeNotesModel = databaseNotes.getNotesByID(pdfList.getId(), final_nav_opt_name);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PDFResults.class);
                intent.putExtra("pdfList", downloadeNotesModel.getFileLocation());
                intent.putExtra("from", "database");
                intent.putExtra("getSubjectName", downloadeNotesModel.getSubjectName());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                alertDialog.setMessage("Notes not downloaded. Do you want to download it?");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        downloader = new Downloader();
                        new CheckSpace().execute(pdfList.getFileName());
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    });

    holder1.imgDownloadNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("PDFListAdapter", "imgDownloadNote position = "+position);
            Log.e("PDFListAdapter", "imgDownloadNote = "+pdfList.getId());
            pdfList = pdfModelClasses.get(position);
            deepak =index ;

            // We don't need the reassignment.
            // holder = holder1;

            if (!databaseNotes.isPurchasedNoteSaved(pdfList.getId(), final_nav_opt_name)) {
                if (UtilsMethods.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        downloader = new Downloader();
                        new CheckSpace().execute(pdfList.getFileName());

                        // Make them visible when the internet connection is there. 
                        holder1.imgDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder1.imgCancelDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder1.progress_download_note.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "storage permission is not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        PermissionCheck.checkWritePermission(context);
                        holder1.imgDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder1.imgCancelDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder1.progress_download_note.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } else {
                    holder1.imgDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder1.imgCancelDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder1.progress_download_note.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NoInternetActivity.class));
                }
            } else { 
                // Put proper visibility everywhere. 
                holder1.imgDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder1.imgCancelDownloadNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder1.progress_download_note.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.e("","Not in db");
            }
        }
    });

    holder1.imgCancelDownloadNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("PDFListAdapter", "imgCancelDownloadNote position = "+position);
            Log.e("PDFListAdapter", "imgCancelDownloadNote = "+pdfList.getId());
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialogStyle).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure want to cancel download?");
            alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    alertDialog.hide();
                    downloader.cancel(true);
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return pdfModelClasses.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```