# recyclerview data changed on scrolling (Not Duplicate) and dynamic textview got doubled on scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, vertical-scrolling

My recyclerview data changed while I scrolling down/up.
when I scroll the layout it appears every time with new values
I've added both methods and as well and false recyclable too. But, didn't work out.

Here's is how my adapter looks like.

```
public class DetailListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<KcResponse> kcList;
String birthDate; }

 @NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_client_detail, parent, false);
    DetailListAdapter.ViewHolder vh = new DetailListAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DetailListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    holder.periodTv.setText(kcList.get(position).getPeriod());

  TextView textView1 = new TextView(context);
    textView1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        String line = arr[i];
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(line);
        ss.setSpan(new BulletSpan(bulletGap), 0, line.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        ssb.append(ss);

        //avoid last "\n"
        if (i + 1 < arr.length)
            ssb.append("\n");

    }

    textView1.setTextSize(12);
    textView1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black_text));
    textView1.setPadding(15, 0, 0, 0);
    textView1.setText(ssb); // bullet text
    holder.effectsLl.addView(textView1);

   holder.periodTv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(kcList.get(position).getColor()));}

 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return kcList.size();
}
```

Comment: please show your adapter file

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  "recyclerview data changed" is not a helpful description.

Comment: Where do you update your `kcList`

Comment: remove this line @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

Comment: @silentsudo tried it but didn't workout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this overriding method to your custom adapter

```
 @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: Didn't Helped me @Ak23

Comment: first remove 
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false); then add above method

Comment: Thanx @Ak23 now the value is not changing but I've added textview (dynamically) in this adapter and it generates multiple times as I scroll.

Comment: Please update your adapter class I not see any textview declaration or dynamically generation.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have more than one type of views in your recylcerview so one thing for sure that you do not need to override `getItemViewType(int position)`.

Also the usage of method `getItemId(int position)` is incorrect. That method is used to get the stable ID for the item at position.

Comment: What is the purpose of `getItemId(int position)` and `getItemViewType(int position)` in your case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43179233/12804233 I've followed this solution for my problem

Comment: I feel, use of `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);` is unnecessary and root of your problem. Please remove all three

Comment: I've removed both methods and recyclable false, Still, my Problem remains same.

Comment: The method was already there -> no you have written its your code, own your code.

Answer (score -1):

The adapter code you shared is not enough to identify the issue. So I am sharing a very simple recyclerview and its adapter code, just try to use that. I hope it will help you.

Happy coding...

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DataAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        adapter = new DataAdapter();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this));
    }
}
```

Adapter class code

```
    public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public DataAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textView.setText("TextView1");
        holder.textView.setText("TextView2");
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 20;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView imageView;
        public TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            this.textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f1f1f1"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

adapter_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```