# RecyclerView item to show the same background color on scrolling

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am new to android, and I am having an issue with my recycler view. I want to have a random color as the profile image background, but the color keeps changing when I swipe up and down some couple of times, I want each item to maintain a particular color. Please how can I achieve this. This is what I have done to randomize the colors:

```
private fun changeClientProfileBackgroundColor ():Drawable?{val colorDrawables = arrayOf(
        R.drawable.client_list_background_color_drawable_1,
        R.drawable.client_list_background_color_drawable_2,
        R.drawable.client_list_background_color_drawable_3,
        R.drawable.client_list_background_color_drawable_4,
        R.drawable.client_list_background_color_drawable_5,
        R.drawable.client_list_background_color_drawable_6 )return ContextCompat.getDrawable(
        context!!, colorDrawables[(Math.random() * 5).roundToInt()])}



binding.clientHomeImageProfileColorBackground.background =
                changeClientProfileBackgroundColor()
```

[Image of the recycler view with the background random colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ9Bv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [getItemViewType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) in recyclerview adapter if your adapter view is not stable.

Check this previous question in stackoverflow for more reference.

[Recyclerview Changing Items During Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065267/recyclerview-changing-items-during-scroll)

Answer (score 0):

To set a random background color or img in each item, please follow this exemple. This exemple use background color but still same process if you want image.

```java
@Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
      studentData data=studentDataList.get(i);
      Random rnd = new Random();
      int currentColor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
      viewHolder.parent.setBackgroundColor(currentColor);
      viewHolder.name.setText(data.name);
      viewHolder.age.setText(String.valueOf(data.age));
   }
```

[image: This is what you excepted to have]

[This tutorial explain in details the procedure](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-set-random-background-for-recyclerview-in-android)

Comment: Hi @codewithbawo, if it worked please vote up and mark it as answered question to help other user seeing this answer.

Comment: I am new here, i need 15 reputation to cast a vote. Thanks